# Resizing an image maintaing aspect ratio 

Tags: ios, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to solve this problem I have, but I feel like there's gotta be a much more simpler, easier solution to this. Here's the problem:

- I have a canvas with width:**cWidth**, and height: **cHeight**.
- I have an image with width: **iWidth** and height **iHeight**. (Image is large than the canvas, both width and height wise)
- I have a rectangle with width: **tWidth** and height: **tHeight**.

The image is inside canvas right now. I can scale(zoom) in or out as much as I can.

The goal is to map the rectangle onto the canvas. Here's an image that explain it much better:
[image]

Of course, the mapped rectangle needs to be centred (vertically and horizontally) as well.

What's the best way to do this?

If anyone wants, I can post my solution, but it's very long and (kinda embarrassing IMO), which is the reason why I am asking this question. But please ask and I will post it here.

Thanks

**Just to clarify:** I need to reposition and resize the **original** image in such a manner that the rectangle area appears in the middle.

Comment: If all you want is to move the original image so the rectangle appears in the middle why do you keep talking about resizing?  If the rectangle is in the middle, it will be in the middle at all scales...  Is there a separate constraint having to do with scaling?    Are you just trying to put the center of the image in the same place as the center of the rectangle?

Comment: The answer below was assuming that this is what your objective was